# How to prove set membership after addition operation?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set, then, $\forall \mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{a} \neq \mathbf{0}$, $\exists \mathbf{x} \in X$ such that $\left(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{x} \right) \notin X$.

Is this proposition always true? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: The notation doesn't make so much sense. But if $X\subset\Bbb R^n$ is compact (and nonempty) it's more or less obvious that there exist $x\in X$ and $a\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $x+a\notin X$. Hint: $X$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks David for the correction. Does "obvious" mean it is trivial to prove?

Comment: Actually I misread the question. It's very easy to prove, not _quite_ as trivial as I was thinking. Ignore my previous hint. Hint: GIven $a\ne0$, there exists $x\in X$ which maximizes $x\cdot a$.